# Patterns to make JRuby On Rails applications suitable for both Rails and Java developers

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, jruby

My team consists of Rails and Java developers working together on the JRuby On Rails application. Rails people prefer to develop the front-end application using the pure Ruby interpreter. Java people deploy application to the Tomcat and integrates it with Spring and core Java back-end services.

We recognize which version of Ruby is executing the project to allow the Rails fellows to develop it using pure Ruby interpreter.

For example we adjust the database configuration:

```
module MyWebApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    def config.database_configuration
      config = super
      if defined? JRUBY_VERSION
        config["development"]["adapter"]="jdbcsqlite3"  
      end
      config
    end
  end
end
```

The same for the Gemfile:

```
gem 'sqlite3'
if defined? JRUBY_VERSION
  gem 'jdbc-sqlite3'
  gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter' 
end
```

We also mock the core Java services:

```
class DocumentServiceFactory
  def build
    if defined? JRUBY_VERSION
      spring_context :document_service
    else
      mock :document_service
    end
  end 
end
```

This solution works for us but I'm curious if there's any general patterns (or plugins, gems, libraries, etc.) for making Rails application both Ruby- and JRuby-friendly?

Comment: You can make java and MRI gems, so it should be handled at the gem level imo.

Comment: Hmmmm... I'm not sure how can I change database adapter at gem level. But yeah, delegating all MRI/JRuby switching logic into gems would be an elegant solution. I'll make some research about this approach. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

there's 3 things to answer here:

1. there has been no need to change the *database.yml* adapter configuration for a while.
   just leave it as `adapter: sqlite3` or mysql etc. and use a recent *activerecord-jdbc-adapter* e.g. *activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter*
2. that's certainly not the correct way to handle jruby specific dependencies in your *Gemfile*. it's much better if you use the `:platform` specifier so that Gemfile.lock is consistent and does no need to be regenerated between ruby switches e.g. :

   `gem 'activerecord-jdbcsqlite3-adapter' :platform -> :jruby`
3. for the service mocks there probably ain't a "better" way but since you mention not all your rubyist use jruby I would consider exposing a service layer e.g. as a REST/Web service so that you do not have to mock every service that gets introduced and rubyist are not confronted with java issues they do not understand (since they do not work on the spring part) even if running with jruby.

other than that, I've been pretty happy with developing/testing on MRI and using JRuby in production, the only real hustle for your ruby folks is to understand they write "truly" `threadsafe!` code (jruby style) and be cautions when adding new gems to make sure they work on both sides or have a jruby alternative ... I had very few incompatibilities with gems running fine on MRI but having issues on JRuby (maybe 3 I can remember). I certainly recommend CI (e.g Jenkins) running your tests with JRuby to catch those early on whenever possible.